# Add installer to a c# application

Tags: c#, templates, installation

I made a search to find how am I adding an installer to my c# application. In every result I found that I need to add new file from Setup and Deployment templates, but I have no those templates. Even in online search I didn't find so.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VS setup templates were removed post VS-2010.

Now, you have to use something else. "InstallShield" is still available, and [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) is a very popular install framework. You can, of course, just roll your own installer as well.

Alternatively, just use VS 2010 or earlier to create your setup/deployment projects.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you should do some research. There are many options out there depending on your type of application. Is it an executable that runs locally? Is it a Web application? Or a mobile application?

Microsoft provides lots of options/guides out of the box. Assuming you use Visual Studio 2013 check this MSDN article which is a good guide to start your research journey: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzawcsz.aspx